# how to implement pause and resume button function using tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, pause

```
Tkinter.Button(self, text='Pause', command=self.pause_program).grid(row=7, columnspan=2, rowspan=3)
    def pause_program(self):

        input("Press Enter to continue...")
        time.sleep(2)
```

and below the other part of the program.
remaining program fetches data from a source, want to implement a pause and resume button to pause the program by simply pressing the button and resume it back whenever needed.

Comment: When do you want to resume your program

Comment: by pressing on a button like pause

Comment: A GUI and `sleep` or `input` in the same thread don't work together. You gave tno information about your actual program so it's hard to give any advice how to implement the pause properly.

Comment: just  do exactly what you did but make the text resume, and command function to resume program , inside your pause program function before time.sleep() add a while loop that checks if the user has not clicked resume yet